# Using Google's Contacts API's, how can I get the user's name and gmail address?

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth

I know how to get the entire contacts list using Google Contacts API (I get a session token and use Google's Zend package for PHP).

But how can I get the person's name and email address? Currently, the Contacts API just seems to give ***all*** of the contacts. I'm not sure how to distinguish which email and name out of that list corresponds to the user's account.

**Is there an easy way to get the user's full name and email address?**

Any help would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

yes goto http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/reference.html#ContactsFeed
and see the "Contacts feed" 
they say to use the Default, it worked for me after using the default - lower case only.

request

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full
```

will give you the user's details.

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/bla@gmail.com/full
```

will give you a contact info (if bla@gmail.com) is a contact.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for the "default" contact (i.e., me), you get what you need.
Mind that you need to write default with a lowercase d and not as written in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

THe xml returned for the default contact list will have the user's name and email within the "author" element.    I don't know PHP, but the code might look something like this...

```
  email = xml["author"].first["email"].first
  name = xml["author"].first["name"].first
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this information by querying :

```
"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token=YourToken123"
```

and parsing your XML (SimpleXML example):

```
$user_email = $xmlResult->id;
$user_name  = $xmlResult->author->name;
```

`$xmlResult->author->name` will give you the whole name as the user has configured it, so it's not certain that you will get in the "FirstName Lastname" format.